# Question on abelian group, does $G/H$ abelian $\iff [G,G]\leq H$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a group and $H\lhd G$ a normal subgroup. I have a theorem that say that if $G/H$ is abelian, then $[G,G]\leq H$. I wondered if the converse hold, does it ?

I recall that $[G,G]=\left<ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\mid g,h\in G\right>$.

Comment: Yes, and in fact if you assume that $[G,G]\leq H$ then $H$ is automatically normal.

Comment: Yes, the converse holds.

Comment: . Yes. A quotient group $G/H$ is commutative iff $H$ contains the commutators.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for all your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $[G,G]\leq H\leq G$.

We have: $$ghg^{-1}=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}h=ah$$ where: $$a:=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\in[G,G]\leq H$$ So $h\in H$ will imply that $ghg^{-1}=ah\in H$. This shows that $H$ is normal.

$G/H$ is abelian since $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba\in H$ (which is true for each pair $a,b\in G$) implies that  $abH=baH$ or equivalently $(aH)(bH)=(bH)(aH)$.